# Data Import Wizard not working

Tags: data-import-wizard

When I try to use the Data Import Wizard (which I have used many times) I am getting the below error.  I do not have a field named status in my import file.  Is anyone else experiencing this problem?  I successfully used the import wizard a week ago.  This appears to be a new problem.  I have logged out and back in & the problem still exists.  I am using a System Administrator account.
[image]

Comment: what object are you trying to upload?

Comment: @cropredy  The data import error was occurring on any object that I tried to import into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined that the problem was caused by the "Salesforce Community Page Optimizer" Chrome extension.  Once I disabled the extension, the data import wizard worked fine.